# Json dependency in passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

my app works fine in mongrel(locally), but suddenly apache with passenger is giving me trouble. It was working fine, but now i get this error which i haven't managed to resolve yet :

```
Could not find multi_json-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

My Gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'tzinfo'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'cancan'

# active-admin dependencies
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'sorcery'

group :assets do
    gem "coffee-script"
    gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
end
```

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

hmm, i noticed in my gems path that the only gem there is "multi_json-1.0.4", which is different than the multi_json-1.1.0 it is asking for. However, when running 'bundle', i see 'Using multi_json (1.1.0)'. But i can't find the gem anywhere(and neither does passenger as it seems).

Comment: Maybe adding gem 'multi_json' will help ?

Comment: I tried that :P Does not work.

Comment: Did you try "bundle show multi_json" ? Gem exists ?

Comment: Is this gem mentioned in your Gemfile.lock? Are you deploying to Passenger or working locally?

Comment: it is mentioned in lock yes. I'm deploying in with Passenger in a remote server and it was working fine some days ago, don't really know why it broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encountered and resolved the same issue after upgrading Ruby from 1.9.2p29- to 1.9.3. I'm using NGINX, not Apache, but here's a combined solution:

1. NGINX only (Apache loads passenger dynamically): rebuild NGINX with
   Passenger after installing Ruby 1.9.3.
2. In the web server's config file, update Passenger's root and ruby assignments with the correct ruby version.

NGINX.conf - in the http {} block:

```
http {
   ...
   passenger_root /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11;
   passenger_ruby /Users/myusername/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ruby;
   ...
}
```

Or, in Apache's httpd.conf:

```
PassengerRoot /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /Users/myusername/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ruby
```

Also, rebundle the app (bundle update).

Hope this works for you.

Re some of the other questions posted in reply.

- gem file exists.  Bundle show:
  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/multi_json-1.1.0
- multi_json is a dependency of Passenger, not the app, so no
  effect/not required in gemfile.
- gemfile.lock irrelevant for above reason; bundle update has no effect

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually going about that type of headache by adding gems directly to my repositories. The caveat is that your repository is growing but I find that less pain than being dependent on gem servers.

```
bundle pack
git add vendor/cache
git commit
```

Then install gems during deployment with the deployment flag

```
bundle install --deployment
```